# fit all floated items in a single row

Tags: css-float, row, css

My Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/trK7C/

HTML:

```
<div class="itemsContainer">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://www.itsalif.info/blogfiles/video-play/vthumb.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="itemsContainer">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://www.itsalif.info/blogfiles/video-play/vthumb.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="itemsContainer">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://www.itsalif.info/blogfiles/video-play/vthumb.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear">
```

CSS:

```
.itemsContainer {
  float: left;
  width : 300px;
  height : 300px;
  margin-left : 2px;
  border : 1px solid black;
  position : relative;
}

.image {
  width : 300px;
  height : 175px;
  margin-bottom : -115px;
  z-index : -1; 
  border : 1px solid green;
}

.image img {
      width : 300px;
  height : 175px;

}
```

3rd item floats to the next row on the page

How can I fit the 3rd item in the same row with no horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: when I increase the size of your fiddle window, it is displayed correctly.. or do you want to achieve desired effect on window with the size of the one on jsFiddle?

Comment: That was just an example assuming the default width in jsfiddle is the max width available like the max browser window/screen size in real use case

Comment: Is it acceptable to resize/downsize the images?

Comment: Try to set width of the images to percentage, like 33%

Comment: in my real use use I dont want to resize images. I am able to to achieve what I asked for with div having display as inline-block. But I am wondering if this can be done with float:left

Comment: you have already achieved it check this http://jsfiddle.net/trK7C/show/

Comment: hmm... then maybe try to set fixed width to a parent container to some 1000px

Comment: @gauravjain can you check this link plz .. http://jsfiddle.net/trK7C/show/

Comment: @shail...I did see that...please see this http://jsfiddle.net/trK7C/11/show/. Please assume if cannot resize the window size

Comment: @gauravjain My question to you is ,How is it possible to incorporate 3 big size images without resizing inside a  screen 480px wide . You will have to resize images to fit the screen size thats resizing.

Comment: The overflown items can be scrolled. With overflow:hidden scrollbar will not be visible. in jquery then i expect to scroll...I hope that clarifies...thats my desired expectation

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/trK7C/4/

change float:left to display:inline-block and wrap all of it in a container with a width big enough to hold it.

```
#container {
    width:940px;
}
.itemsContainer {
    display:inline-block;
    width : 300px;
    height : 300px;
    margin-left : 2px;
    border : 1px solid black;
    position : relative;
}

<div id="container"> <!-- holds all the html in the fiddle -->
```

Comment: as i mentioned above I was able to do it using display:inline-block, can this be done with float:left? not possible? pardon my ignorance

Comment: @gauravjain, the same result will be if you will replace display:inline-block; to float:left; in the example above

Comment: @gauravjain The issue is not display or float. The issue is that both are designed to wrap to the width of their container. I just prefer inline-block especially for div's. You might be able to figure out something with overflow but that will likely make a scroll bar.

Comment: I will stick to inline-block. Although I am still curious if this can be done with float as well. I will accept your answer on Monday waiting for couple more responses...thanks again